# IOS: How to make a tab bar on the left on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

[image]

[image]

I've seen many apps creating a side bar on the left like the image above.  Apparently this is not a split view controller since the size is fix for that.

Anyone know how to do it? May I get some directions or advice on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done simply by adding to your main view a `UIView` with a "vertical" frame, e.g. (0, 0, 44, screenHeight). That view should be then populated with all the icons you need...

There is nothing more to it, as far as I can see.

Comment: except you cannot push viewcontrollers from views... this is an awful way to do what he wanted.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: actually, I have never meant to push a view controller from anywhere…  never talked of view controllers… if you want to have a view controller, define your custom tab bar view (as I suggested), then build you custom tab bar controller around it and use view controller containment (no pushing), and that's it.

Answer (score 5):

It is shown [in this tutorial](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/ios-5-creating-a-custom-side-tabbar-using-storyboards-and-custom-segues/), how you can implement that kind of "custom side Tab Bar", he did a video about it too.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the default UITabBarController from iOS. You will need to do your custom tab bar. You could use an UIView with some UIButtons added as subviews.